# WNS push notification never fires Activated event when app is suspended

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

My head started to spin: I have a windows phone 8.1 universal app. In App.xaml.cs I have implemented the following methods:

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public static bool isSuspended = false;

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;
        this.Resuming += this.OnResuming;
    }

    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendingDeferral deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        App.isSuspended = true;

        // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private async void OnResuming(object sender, object e)
    {
        App.isSuspended = false;
    }
}
```

In my MainPageVM (it is a View Model) I have implemented the following methods:

```
private async void onPushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.NotificationType)
    {
        case PushNotificationType.Toast:
            if (App.isSuspended)
            {
                args.ToastNotification.Activated += this.toastNotification_Activated;
            }
            else
            {
                args.Cancel = true;
                this.manageNotification(args.ToastNotification.Content)
            }
            break;
        case PushNotificationType.Raw:
            break;
    }
}

private void toastNotification_Activated(ToastNotification sender, object args)
{
    ToastActivatedEventArgs tArgs = (ToastActivatedEventArgs)args;
    this.manageNotification(tArgs.Arguments);
}
```

It runs well when the app is killed or when the app is in foreground. The problem comes when the app is in background: when user clicks the notification, `toastNotification_Activated` never gets raised.

What am I missing?

Comment: When your app is suspended it's not performing any action, running any code or other. It just stays in memory and in some conditions it may be termianated by OS. Your code `if (App.isSuspended)` won't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is *Suspended* it means that it's not running ([app lifecycle at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx)). In this case when the notification comes it's not intercepted by the event you have declared, like [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709907.aspx):

> **Note**  This procedure applies only to running apps. Notifications that the system sends when the app is not running and the handler is not implemented are delivered normally—tiles are updated, toast is shown, and raw notifications are delivered to background tasks (if implemented).

If you want to handle the notification in the background, then you may think of declaring a [Background Task for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709906.aspx).